# What do you call the question type in a quiz game where you have to order the answers?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the proper name for these type of questions? These are the questions like the 'Fastest Fingers First' questions in Who Wants to Be a Millionaire.

Can you call them *'ordering' questions* or *'order the answers' questions* or is there a proper name?

I found the following names for other types:

- **Simple answer**: when you have no choices, you have to type or tell.
- **Multiple Choice**: when you have to choose one.
- **True/False**: when you have to decide if the information given is right or wrong.

Comment: What you are calling "simple answer" is what I think I've usually heard called "short answer". Or if it calls for a long answer, an "essay question".

Comment: Or "open question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are sometimes referred to as ordering questions. For example (from a help guide for the Blackboard™ Learning Management System):

> **[Ordering Questions](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/isolutions/computing/elearn/blackboard/questiontypes.html)**
>
> *Ordering questions require students to provide an answer by selecting the correct order of a series of items. For example, you can give
>   students a list of historical events and ask them to place these
>   events in chronological order.*

Some purists will point out that an ordering question is simply a special kind of a matching question.  For example, you might have an ordering question that reads:

> Rank the following from earliest to latest:
>
> - a) signing of the Treaty of Ghent
> - b) signing of the Declaration of    Independence
> - c) signing of the Emancipation Proclamation
> - d) signing of the Magna Carta

This is essentially a much "cleaner" way of asking:

> Match the items in the top list with the correct description in the bottom list:
>
> - 1) signing of the Treaty of Ghent
> - 2) signing of the Declaration of Independence
> - 3) signing of the Emancipation Proclamation
> - 4) signing of the Magna Carta
>
> ---
>
> - a) the earliest of the four events
> - b) the second-earliest of the four events
> - c) the secondmost-recent of the four events
> - d) the most recent of the four events

(although, from a technical standpoint, the two questions are essentially the same).

Comment: c should be "the penultimate event" and b "the antepenultimate event". http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/is-penultimate-commonly-used

Comment: Well, maybe, but you could make that kind of quibble about other types, too. Like isn't true/false a special case of multiple choice, where the choices are true and false?

Comment: @Jay: Absolutely.  I only mentioned it because some academicians find that to be an interesting viewpoint, and EL&U seems to have a lot of members from that profession.  No "quibbling" was intended; just an incidental footnote.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. The other two are also valid answers but I can accept only one. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could call it a "sequencing question".

Answer (score 0):

I’d call it a *ranking question*.